# Java Library paths issues

Tags: java, classpath, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have the following JNI shared library  located in /data/subv/Mem, I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to :

```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/subv/Mem
```

which contains two files: bmemBridgelib.so and memBridgelib.so, generated using:

```
  gcc -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux" -o 
  libmemBridgelib.so -shared -Wl,-soname,libmemBridge.so JniBridge.c -static -lc -fPIC
```

I load the library in my Java program to use JNI as follows

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("memBridgelib");
}
```

but get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no memBridgelib in java.library.path
```

When i print the library path, i can confirm that the mem folder isn't in it:

```
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Any ideas? All the other related questions seem to be solved by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java -Djava.library.path=/data/ncrooks/subv/stream-paas/Mem[:<other_lib_paths>] ...
```

[More details](http://kalblogs.blogspot.com/2009/01/java.html).

Comment: This overwrites the whole classpath though. and i'm compiling my program with a gradlew script that I can't really modify ... I agree though that that would be the simple answer :p

Comment: @user1018513 - it doesn't affect the _classpath_, and yes, it is the only solution.  if you need _other_ things on the library path, add them as well.

Comment: why does LD_LIBRARY_PATH not work for this? seemed to work for other

Comment: I was curious why setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH worked in other questions I'd seen but not this one. I ended up asking for permission to modify the script. Works fine now. Thanks